# Paylocity API get employee department

Tags: paylocity

Does anyone know how to retrieve department from the Employee API? As per the online documentation, the Employee structure does not have a property for department?

I need this to be able sync some data into Azure AD.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your company implemented departments, but this worked for us:

```
DepartmentCostCenter1 = employee.Value.departmentPosition == null ? null : employee.Value.departmentPosition.costCenter1,
DepartmentCostCenter2 = employee.Value.departmentPosition == null ? null : employee.Value.departmentPosition.costCenter2,
DepartmentCostCenter3 = employee.Value.departmentPosition == null ? null : employee.Value.departmentPosition.costCenter3,
DepartmentPositionCode = employee.Value.departmentPosition == null ? null : employee.Value.departmentPosition.positionCode,
```